# eth0 not working on copied VMWare fusion VM

Tags: macos, ubuntu, vmware-fusion

When you copy a VM in VMWare fusion - you simply copy the folder of VM files.

When you start up the copied one - VMWare will ask you if you copied it or moved - select copied.

Then inside the VM, you may not get eth0 networking (even though it has a new MAC address) - what is going on? (Specifically was Ubuntu server in this case).

Comment: Thanks for moving from SO to SU whoever did it ! Mucho appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to look in /etc/udev/rules.d/ and there will be files that remember what peripherals are connected - delete these (especially any ones to to with networking) and restart - and it should pick up the "new" adapter and mac address just fine.

Found answer buried here: http://communities.vmware.com/thread/46069

Comment: That's right. The server remembers the MAC address, and maps MAC address to the interface name. If the MAC address changes (it does when you copy a VM), the guest will create a new interface. Most modern Linux use a peristent udev rule for that, but notably RedHat (and derivatives) adds an ifcfg-ethX entry with the MAC address.

Comment: yes, exactly. This was ubuntu's latest LTS server. Is a bit annoying it does this - would be a common thing to do. Hopefully this helps people out.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with Ubuntu 11 desktop VM, which I had earlier copied and upgraded from 10.10. The network was set to bridged mode, and it was working fine for several hours. Then it stopped working. First I suspected it might have been a problem with my DHCP server, because I could no longer log into my router. However, even after I rebooted my router, ifconfig refused to show an inet address. After trying many things, I decided to shutdown the VM, remove the network adapter from the settings, then re-add it. When I restarted the VM, the eth0 magically started to work again!